# 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 102) near <eof>

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am getting this error

> 'end' expected (to close 'function' at line 102) near

```lua
button:addEventListener("tap", function()

buttonText.isVisible=false
button.isVisible=false
sun.isVisible=false
myText.isVisible=false
myText=display.newText("Rock, Paper, Scissors",w*.5,h*.1,native.systemFont,30)
myText:setFillColor(unpack(limegreen))

options={"rock","paper","scissors"}
computerChoice=options[math.random(3)]

local rockButton = display.newRoundedRect(w*.5,h*.3,w*.5,h*.2,25)
rockButton.anchorX=.5
rockButton.anchorY=.5
rockButton:setFillColor(unpack(redorange))
local rockText=display.newText("Rock",w*.5,h*.3,systemFont,50)
rockText:setFillColor(unpack(blue))

local paperButton = display.newRoundedRect(w*.5,h*.6,w*.5,h*.2,25)
paperButton.anchorX=.5
paperButton.anchorY=.5
paperButton:setFillColor(unpack(redorange))
local paperText=display.newText("Paper",w*.5,h*.6,systemFont,50)
paperText:setFillColor(unpack(blue))

local scissorsButton = display.newRoundedRect(w*.5,h*.9,w*.5,h*.2,25)
scissorsButton.anchorX=.5
scissorsButton.anchorY=.5
scissorsButton:setFillColor(unpack(redorange))
local scissorsText=display.newText("Scissors",w*.5,h*.9,systemFont,50)
scissorsText:setFillColor(unpack(blue))

rockButton:addEventListener("tap",function()
rockButton.isVisible=false
rockText.isVisible=false
paperButton.isVisible=false
paperText.isVisible=false
scissorsButton.isVisible=false
scissorsText.isVisible=false
playerChoice="rock"
local computerChoiceText=display.newText("Computer's Choice: "..computerChoice,w*.5,h*.3,native.systemfont,25)

if computerChoice=="paper" then
   local whoWonText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You LOST!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)

elseif computerChoice=="scissors" then
   local whoWontText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You WON!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)

else
   local whoWontText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You TIE!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)
end

paperButton:addEventListener("tap",function()
rockButton.isVisible=false
rockText.isVisible=false
paperButton.isVisible=false
paperText.isVisible=false
scissorsButton.isVisible=false
scissorsText.isVisible=false
playerChoice="paper"
local computerChoiceText=display.newText("Computer's Choice: "..computerChoice,w*.5,h*.3,native.systemfont,25)

if computerChoice=="paper" then
   local whoWonText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You Tie!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)

elseif computerChoice=="scissors" then
   local whoWontText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You WON!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)

else
   local whoWontText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You TIE!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)
end

scissorsButton:addEventListener("tap",function()
rockButton.isVisible=false
rockText.isVisible=false
paperButton.isVisible=false
paperText.isVisible=false
scissorsButton.isVisible=false
scissorsText.isVisible=false
playerChoice="scissors"
local computerChoiceText=display.newText("Computer's Choice: "..computerChoice,w*.5,h*.3,native.systemfont,25)

if computerChoice=="paper" then
   local whoWonText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You WON!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)

elseif computerChoice=="scissors" then
   local whoWontText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You TIE!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)

else
   local whoWontText=display.newText("Player Choice: "..playerChoice.."You LOST!",w*.5,h*.5,native.systemFont,20)
end
end)
```

I have an `end` for each of the functions

I've gone through my code multiple times, and just cant find what's wrong, and I keep getting the same error, but occasionally on different lines if I try to fix it by adjusting parentheses.
Someone suggested properly indenting it, but I'm still getting the error

Comment: There's a reason why you should use proper indentation. And you've encountered it.

Comment: @NicolBolas its kind of hard to indent when the program you use uses notepad

Comment: I did it for years before they invented IDEs that would automatically indent code. And right now, you're basically asking someone else to do that for you.

Comment: @NicolBolas didn't mean to come across that way, it had been working perfectly fine for me without indentation before, so it was confusing me, I'll go through it and indent, and see if that works

Comment: @NicolBolas just went through it and indented everything properly (after learning how to properly indent lua) and I am still getting the same error

Comment: It'd be a good idea if you posted your "properly indented" code.

Comment: @NicolBolas I updated the code in my question to the indented one

Comment: "*I updated the code in my question to the indented one*" One sign that your "properly indent"ed code is not that is seeing two `end`s back-to-back at the *same* level of indentation. Also, I see several nested `function`s without indentation.

Comment: @NicolBolas I figured it out, I had only closed the main function.

Answer (score 0):

For each of your anonymous listener functions, they do not appear to be ended at all.  For example, assuming that the first listener should be ended after the limegreen text, you would change this:

```
button:addEventListener("tap", function()

buttonText.isVisible=false
button.isVisible=false
sun.isVisible=false
myText.isVisible=false
myText=display.newText("Rock, Paper, Scissors",w*.5,h*.1,native.systemFont,30)
myText:setFillColor(unpack(limegreen))

options={"rock","paper","scissors"}
```

to this:

```
button:addEventListener("tap", 
    function()
        buttonText.isVisible=false
        button.isVisible=false
        sun.isVisible=false
        myText.isVisible=false
        myText=display.newText("Rock, Paper, Scissors",w*.5,h*.1,native.systemFont,30)
        myText:setFillColor(unpack(limegreen))
    end )

options={"rock","paper","scissors"}
```

The `end` closes off the anonymous function.
The trailing `)` closes off the start of `addEventListener`.